# Data from SQLite gets lost on application update

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, updating

I've got a problem with application update.
All the user settings are kept in SQLite DB inside key-value table. Before I kept the settings in shared preferences, but on update they got deleted.
As the DB is safe on update I moved all the settings in the DB, and everything worked fine. But not always. Most of the time on update all the data is lost.
If earlier all the 'data' folder got removed, now only the DB is removed. Though `onUpgrade` method is never called. In Android Manifest `android:allowBackup="true"` and `android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"`

Here is my backup_descriptor file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <include domain="database"
    path="." />
    <include domain="sharedpref"
             path="." />
</full-backup-content>
```

And here is the part of my `DBHelper` class:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "create database");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE KV(name varchar(256) primary key, value varchar(256))");
        fillSettings(db);

    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Обновление базы
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.format("--- onUpgrade settings --- from %d to %d", oldVersion, newVersion));
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Обновление базы настроек!");
        }
    }
```

I tried to install application over adb, over file manager and even over Play Market. In every case there was the following situation:
For example, I install app v8, do some changes and they are saved. Then I update my app to v9 and don't open it, I go check if the files (DB) exist, and they are not.

I really can't understand why it happens and I hope you can help me.
I tried to find something like that on Stackoverflow, but the common problem is how to remove data on update, while I can't save it :(

UPD: I know when I need to use onUpgrage method and I understand how it works. But I don't understand why the system clears data on my device. I tried test this on emulators with the same device and OS version (My device is Nexus 5x) and the problem doesn't appear. Why? 
I apologize for the grammar, I don't know English well.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ADD_COLUMN_!);
    }
    if (oldVersion < 3) {
         db.execSQL(DATABASE_ADD_COLUMN_2);
    }
}
```

I found [this](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/how-android-sqlite-onupgrade) tutorial most helpful with SQlite upgrades.